# SQL AFTER INSERT,UPDATE Trigger with condition if update specific column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I would like to create a trigger that inserts new datasets into the FREE08 table (see example code) either after insert on FREE03. This part works. But i also want to insert new dataset into FREE08 only if specific column (FK2) of FREE03 is updated. Thought this works with the "IF UPDATE(FK2) statement in the trigger. 
What happens is i got a new dataset in FREE08 everytime i have any update in FREE03.
How can i get that?

Thanks for your support

```
   USE [DB]
    GO

    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Einsatzhistorie Wechsler] 
       ON  [dbo].[FREE03]
       AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
    AS
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      IF UPDATE(FK2)

    BEGIN

                            INSERT INTO FREE08
    (
    FK1,FK2,TEXT3,DATE1,TEXT2,DATE4
    ) 
    Select FK2,FK1,ID,DATE1,TEXT1,DATE11 From inserted 
                end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never found a real use for the `UPDATE` function, since it tells you *whether a column was subject to `UPDATE`* (I.e. appeared in the `SET` clause), not whether data actually changed. In addition, of course, triggers fire once per statement, not once per row, so your trigger may be dealing with a mixture of rows, *some* of which had their `FK2` changed and some not.

It's usually better to use `deleted` and compare the previous/current values:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[Einsatzhistorie Wechsler] 
   ON  [dbo].[FREE03]
   AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

INSERT INTO FREE08
(
FK1,FK2,TEXT3,DATE1,TEXT2,DATE4
) 
Select i.FK2,i.FK1,i.ID,i.DATE1,i.TEXT1,i.DATE11
From inserted i
left join deleted d
on
   i.ID = d.ID and
   i.FK2 = d.FK2
where d.ID is null
```

Here I've assumed a) that `ID` represents an immutable primary key for the table and b) That `FK2` isn't nullable.